# How to make a coordinate system for a labyrinth?

Tags: c

I have a project where i need to make the program solve an already made labyrinth, thing is that i need coordinates and i don't know how to make them work.

Example of a labyrinth:

```
*************
*          F*
*  **** * * *
*  **   * * *
*  ** *** * *
*S          *
*************
```

S = Start, F, finish.

I load the labyrinth like this: `./labyrinth.exe labyrinth_1.txt`

In my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  FILE *f; 

    f=fopen(argv[1],"r"); 
         if( f==NULL ){
               printf("Archive not found\n");
         }
       else
          {
                while( !feof(f) )
                     printf("%c", getc(f));
          }

        if(!strcmp(argv[2], "-solution")) {
          system("clear"); 
          FILE *r;
          r=fopen("lab1.txt", "r");
            while( !feof(r) ) 
              printf("%c", getc(r));
        } else {
          system("clear");
          printf("Command not found\n");

        }

}
```

- **I need to create a function where i have the coordinates to work with the opened file, but i don't know where to start from, it's
  really confusing me how should i define the array or whatever it has
  to be defined. The function will be recursive to make the program start finding the solution for the labyrinth.** *Side note: I'm only requesting help with knowing how can i make a coordinate system for this to let it solve it.*

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "a coordinate system" is not clear enough. Please describe what you need the coordinate system for. How would you test an answer? What would you do when you have a coordinate system? Would you for example be satisfied by a function `char coordsystem(int x, in y)` which returns the char found at coordinate x,y?

Comment: Do you know the size of the labyrinth (width x heigth) in advance? Your goal would be easier to achieve with that information.

Comment: I need the coordinate system to solve the labyrinth. It will be checking if There is a wall or an empty space for it to walk over it. I don’t know if this cleared your question.

Comment: Please elaborate "It will be checking if There is a wall or an empty space for it to walk over it". I assume that "it" is the coordinate system. How would you use it to do what you describe?  Would you for example be satisfied by a function char coordsystem(int x, in y) which returns the char found at coordinate x,y? If not please show code how you want to use the coordinate system for "checking if There is a wall or an empty space for it to walk over it." Please consider whether a function with the prototype proposed would solve your problem. Otherwise define a different one.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to declare an array of chars like

> char lab[30][30];

or so. Then you read your file, line per line, in lab[0], lab[1] and so on.

Once you are done, you can check every single cell with the notation lab[x][y]; such notation returns a char which can be easily tested against a meaningful char like '*', ' ', 'S', 'F'.

Declaring a static array implies that you choose fairly large limits (sizes of the array), and perhaps you must check that your labyrinth fits into that array.

Note that if the labyrinth is correctly defined in the text file, swapping x and y coordinates has no importance - the labyrinth should be well (always) delimited by '*' (in fact, the coordinate system would be lab[y,x]...).

Once you are sure about the labyrinth and the array(s) repesenting it, you can "move" your explorer (a man who tries to escape the labyrinth) by incrementing and decrementing the y,x indexes. lab[0][0] would be the upper-left cells, lab[0,1] would be the cell next to the right and so on.

Find the way out! :-)